# Put a text on the left top corner of a tabular

Tags: tables

I have several `tabular` as follows in my article. To save some space, I don't want `Step 2` to occupy a whole line, maybe just putting it on the left top corner of the `tabular` is a good idea...

Does anyone know how to realize it?

```
\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\begin{document}
\noindent Step 2:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    &$\begin{array}{C{\widthof{$0$}}|*{3}{C{\widthof{$-2$}}}}
      & i &  0\\ \hline
      i & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    \end{array}$ \quad
    &$\left(\begin{array}{C{\widthof{$0$}}|*{2}{C{\widthof{$-7$}}}|*{2}{C{\widthof{$-7$}}}}
        & x & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} & i & 0 \\ \hline
        x & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 0 & 0 \\
        y & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  &  \\ \cline{4-5}
        i & 0 & & 0 &0\\ 
        0 & 0 &  & 0 & 0
      \end{array}\quad,\text{int}\right)$ \quad \quad
    &$\begin{array}{C{\widthof{$0$}}|*{3}{C{\widthof{$-2$}}}}
      & i &  0\\ \hline
      i & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \end{array}$ \quad
    &$\left(\begin{array}{C{\widthof{$0$}}|*{2}{C{\widthof{$-7$}}}|*{2}{C{\widthof{$-7$}}}}
        & x & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} & i & 0 \\ \hline
        x & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 0 & 0 \\
        y & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  &  \\ \cline{4-5}
        i & 0 & & 0 &0\\ 
        0 & 0 &  & 0 & 0
      \end{array}\quad ,\text{int}\right)$
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
  \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    & Step 2\\[-\normalbaselineskip] %%%%%%%%% new %%%%%%%%%%%%
    &$\begin{array}{C{\widthof{$0$}}|*{3}{C{\widthof{$-2$}}}}
      & i &  0\\ \hline
      i & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    \end{array}$ \quad
 ...
```

[image]

or as an alternetive:

`Step 2\\[-\normalbaselineskip]` %% without the `&`

Answer (score 2):

change

```
\noindent Step 2:
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{lllll}
```

to

```
\begin{center}
  Step 2: \begin{tabular}[t]{lllll}
```